# Trying to loop through an ExtendScript function with a delay

Tags: jsx, extendscript, after-effects

I have an After Effects .jsx ExtendScript file that loops through an array executing a particular function. Rather than simply using a for loop based on the length of the array, I need to delay each iteration by roughly 0.5-1sec but cannot figure it out.

I’ve tried using setInterval and app.setSchedule but neither worked. $.delay() I think works but halts everything rather than simply delaying the particular function.

Comment: i don't know the ExtendScript but is it available `Promise` or do i have to write a simple `promise` polyfill for it

Answer (score 0):

use `setTimeout`:

```js
const fns = [
  () => console.log("1"),
  () => console.log("2"),
  () => console.log("3"),
  () => console.log("4")
]

function run(i = 0) {
  fns[i]()
  
  if (i === fns.length - 1) return
  setTimeout(() => run(i + 1), 1000 /* 1 seconds */)
}

run()
```

Comment: This refers to ExtendScript. There is neither `setTimeout()`, nor `console.log()` nor arrow functions in ExtendScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$.sleep(500)` to delay the execution by half a second. `$.delay()` is not a thing.